# How can I use levelplot to show data only at observed indices?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'm trying to make a (lattice) levelplot. I have a data frame whose columns are the *i* and *j* spatial coordinates of each value I want to plot, those data values (here, *d*), and a column named `fname` (i.e., filename, but there is only a single filename in the dataset I'm using here).

My problem is that `levelplot` is plotting or joining (or something!) data where there are no associated *i* and *j* values (see the example image, below). There is no data for 60 < *j* < 75, but values are being plotted at these locations.

[image: Problematic levelplot]

The plot is created by:

```
pl <- levelplot(d ~ j * i | fname, data = my.data.frame)
print(pl)
```

What don't I understand? How do I correct this? There should be a vertical strip of white (where there is no data), in the approximate range 60 < *j* < 75.

**EDIT**

Below is a fairly minimal example, "zooming in" on the original plot:

`my.data.frame` is:

```
    i  j  d
599 78 56 1.355702e-01
600 77 56 6.296867e-02
601 76 56 1.489721e-01
602 75 56 1.063881e-01
603 74 56 1.544339e-01
604 73 56 1.937138e-01
605 72 56 1.313793e-01
606 71 56 1.220090e-01
631 76 57 8.457023e-02
632 75 57 1.256807e-01
633 74 57 4.346455e-02
634 73 57 5.839973e-02
635 72 57 1.099435e-01
636 71 57 1.648284e-01
662 73 58 7.551661e-02
663 72 58 7.197449e-02
664 71 58 6.525586e-02
700 79 79 1.655431e-01
701 78 79 3.587718e-01
702 77 79 3.285322e-01
703 76 79 2.604316e-01
704 75 79 3.154260e-01
705 74 79 1.599363e-01
706 73 79 1.006594e-01
707 72 79 1.143150e-01
708 71 79 3.442250e-02
743 79 80 1.929037e-01
744 78 80 1.828739e-01
745 77 80 2.542400e-01
746 76 80 3.679110e-01
747 75 80 4.160630e-01
748 74 80 2.187383e-01
749 73 80 5.914896e-02
750 72 80 8.890981e-02
751 71 80 1.114226e-01
785 79 81 1.934852e-01
786 78 81 3.357556e-01
787 77 81 2.223992e-01
788 76 81 2.753734e-01
789 75 81 3.602629e-01
790 74 81 1.813481e-01
791 73 81 7.269607e-02
792 72 81 8.458230e-02
793 71 81 2.189210e-01
825 79 82 2.449923e-01
826 78 82 2.649659e-01
827 77 82 2.701585e-01
828 76 82 2.036100e-01
829 75 82 2.162900e-01
830 74 82 2.097996e-01
831 73 82 9.479770e-02
832 72 82 1.349027e-01
833 71 82 7.756859e-02
863 79 83 1.841222e-01
864 78 83 2.462909e-01
865 77 83 4.760483e-01
866 76 83 1.393683e-01
867 75 83 1.849111e-01
868 74 83 1.072082e-01
869 73 83 1.453932e-01
870 72 83 8.461537e-02
871 71 83 3.600376e-02
899 79 84 2.223011e-01
900 78 84 2.266368e-01
901 77 84 2.682749e-01
902 76 84 1.535989e-01
903 75 84 8.656537e-02
904 74 84 1.155910e-01
905 73 84 1.550887e-01
906 72 84 1.052334e-05
907 71 84 9.409200e-03
```

Then create the "zoomed-in" plot with:

```
library(lattice)
pl <- levelplot(d ~ j * i, data = my.data.frame)
print(pl)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you isolate and provide a subset of the data that also exhibits this behavior?  That will help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks, Josh: a minimal-ish example is now included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`levelplot()` will work most predictably when supplied with a data.frame that has values for each of the cells (i.e. every combination of row and column coordinates) in the grid you'd like to plot. To that end, I've written a smal function that will 'fill out' this particular data set, as well as other data.frames like it that are missing rows for some of the pixels that you need to be plotting.

Using it (or something like it) should save you the hassle of mucking around 'by hand', trying to figure out which cells are missing data. (For example, it turns out that even the small subset of data you provided is missing values from some cells outside of that central strip of obviously missing data.)

```
library(lattice)

makeFullGrid <- function(dat) {
    ## Create a list with coordinates for a full grid and all
    ## values set to 0
    fullgrid <-
        with(dat, expand.grid(i = seq(max(i), min(i)),
                              j = seq(min(j), max(j)),
                              D = 0))
    ## Merge it with your current data, then add the two data
    ## columns together
    dat <- merge(fullgrid, dat, by = c("j", "i"), all.x=TRUE)
    dat$d <- dat$d + dat$D
    dat$D <- NULL         ## Clean up
    return(dat)
}    

## Fix up your data
myDat <- my.data.frame
myFullDat <- makeFullGrid(myDat)

## Create the levelplot
pl <- levelplot(d ~ j * i, data = myFullDat)
print(pl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally plotting functions honor NA values with no point or color so with your data this seems to deliver on your request:

```
nadat <- expand.grid(i=71:80, j=63:78)
 nadat$d <- NA
 pl <- levelplot(d ~ j * i, data = rbind(dat,nadat) )
 print(pl)
```

(By the way that looks like a scan of lung fields with the mediastinum blanked out. Or am I just showing my medical background to a statistical Rorschach?)

Comment: Thanks for your input. And yes, the data is derived from lung imaging.